# Why are consts different to simple objects javascript

Tags: javascript, object, constants

when i work in javascript canvas, when i created a basic object for aqngles like thius

```
const Angle = 
{
  Beginning:0*Math.PI,
  OneQuarter:0.5*Math.PI,
  TwoQuarter:1.0*Math.PI,
  End:2*Math.Pi
}
```

and when i console log the outputs i get this:

```
0
NaN
```

but at the same time when i create unique consts for each like so:

```
const 
startAngle = 0*Math.PI,
endAngle = 2*Math.PI;
```

and i console log it i get the response i want:

```
0
6.283185307179586
```

why does this happen? and how can i create a simple object with calculation and get a correct response? Thanks
Repl page:
https://repl.it/@Ballatoilet/EMDR

Comment: Your code should be posted **here**. Stack Overflow has everything you need to show code that's runnable.

Answer (score 2):

You have typo, it should be `End:2*Math.PI` and you have `End:2*Math.Pi` (small "i" letter).

Comment: Please mark the question as typo instead of answering.